# Material Table not reflecting changes on datasource

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, angular-material

This is my first question in Stack Overflow. I'll try to be specific but I don't know how to keep this short, so this is going to be a long post. Sorry about that. I promise I searched and tried a lot of stuff before asking, but I'm kind of lost now.

I'm developing a simple app in Angular 6 to keep track of software requisites and the tests associated to those requisites.

- I have a component, called **RequisiteList**, whose HTML part consists in a mat-table with an Array of my own **Requisite** model class as [dataSource]. This array is received as an @Input parameter, and it also has an @Output parameter which is an EventEmitter that notifies and passes to the parent component every time a **Requisite** on the list is clicked.
- I make use of **RequisiteList** inside of **ReqListMain**, which is a component consisting on the list and a hierarchical tree for filtering. This component is working fine, showing, and filtering requisites as intended. This component also captures the @Output event of the list and passes it as an @Output to its parent.
- Finally (for what it's related to this question), I have a **TestView** component that has both an instance of **RequisiteList** to show the requisites currently associated to current test, and an instance of **ReqListMain** to add new requisites to current test (like a "browser"). This **TestView** has an instance of the model class **Pectest** corresponding to the test that is being currently visualized, which has an array of **Requisite**.

The idea in this last component was that whenever a requisite of the "browser" list was clicked, it was added to the current test's list. In order to do that, in the callback method associated to the @Output event of the browser list, I tried to add the **Requisite** received as a parameter:

```
addrequisite(requisite: Requisite) {
this.currentTest.requisites.push(requisite);
console.log('Current test: ');
console.log(this.currentTest);
}
```

In the HTML part of **TestView**, I inserted the **RequisiteList** component like this:

```
<app-requisitelist [requisites]="currentTest.requisites" ngModel name="reqlistview"></app-requisitelist>
```

(The **ngModel** property is part of the things I've been trying, I'm not sure it's necessary).

The result is:

- The clicked requisite is not shown in the list.
- In the console output I can see the content of **currentTest** object, and I verify that clicked requisites are in fact added to the requisites array of that object, so the event fires and the object is passed upwards by the children components.

I'm not sure if my problem is that data binding is made by value (I don't think so, as I bind an Array, which is an object AFAIK), or the table is not detecting data changes (I've tried to force data change detection with ChangeDetector), or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a array to the `app-requisitelist` component. This component waits this array changes to update the content. When you do `this.currentTest.requisites.push(requisite)`, the array `this.currentTest.requisites` doesn't change, I mean, if you do

```
const tmp = this.currentTest.requisites;
this.currentTest.requisites.push(requisite)
if (tmp === this.currentTest.requisites) {
    console.log('The arrays are the same');
}
```

You will get the log printed. So, I suggest do something like that:

```
addrequisite(requisite: Requisite) {
    this.currentTest.requisites.push(requisite);
    this.currentTest.requisites = this.currentTest.requisites.map(item => item);
    console.log('Current test: ');
    console.log(this.currentTest);
}
```

The inserted line forces `this.currentTest.requisites` to be a new array with the same content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right in the fact that the object doesn't seem to change (the log line is printed), but the suggested code doesn't work either. 

Maybe there is something similar to Linux's "touch" command, to tell Angular that the array has been updated? It sounds like something that the push() method would do, but I don't know...

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in https://stackblitz.com or http://jsfiddle.net and post the link here?